# "He is better and superior to me" vs "He is better than and superior to me"

Tags: sentence-structure

Came across this question asking which one is correct, four given options are

> 1.He is better and superior than me.
>
> 2.He is better than and superior to me.
>
> 3.He is better and superior to me.
>
> 4.He is better to and superior than me.

The answer provided is **3**. Doesn't **3** violate parallelism? I think **2** would be more accurate.

NB. The book's answers aren't impervious to mistakes.

Comment: I think you mean “violate” not “violet”.  Two is the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the sentence is being parsed. The second sentence is definitely correct. The third sentence *could* be correct.

With the second sentence:

> ✔ He is better than and superior to me.
>   → He is **(better than)** and **(superior to)** me.
>
> He is **better than** me.
>   He is **superior to** me.

---

But the second sentence can be parsed in two different ways.

First, the parsing where it is incorrect:

> ✘ He is better and superior to me.
>   → He is **(better *to*)** and **(superior to)** me.
>
> He is **better than** me.
>   He is **superior to** me.

Now, the parsing of the same text where it is correct:

> ✔ He is better and superior to me.
>   → He is **(better)** and **(superior to me)**.
>
> He is **better**.
>   He is **superior to** me.

---

The answer in the book *could* be correct, *if* the third sentence is parsed in the right way. Otherwise, it's wrong.

But at best, there are *two* correct answers to the question—and no matter how you parse the third sentence, the second sentence will *always* be correct.

Answer (score 3):

### Technically, #2 is correct, though you're probably more likely to hear #3 in day-to-day conversation.

It's not technically correct, but practical speech often breaks the rules due to style or laziness.

That said, the sentences, as a group, are redundant. You would say "He is superior" or "He is better than me" but not both.

Answer (score 2):

Only the second sentence is grammatical, but it is not so idiomatic.

If one person is superior to another, they are better than the other person. So one of the adjectives in the sentence is redundant. It is more idiomatic if you say:

"He is better than me" or "He is superior to me".

Comment: Perhaps this question intends to asses understanding of parallelism.